# change carousel content from images to background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Lads
I'm working on this tabbed carousel. Right now it has no defined height and uses images stretched to 100% to fill the screen. I don't like the way it works.

Instead I would like to set a background image for each slide. This way, I can set a defined height for the carousel, and also set the background to cover so it fills the div nicely.

I've tried a few things over the last hour or two and have had zero luck.

[Check out the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27x8e997/2/)

Here's my HTML

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff">
       <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Headline</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End Item -->

     <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
       <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Headline</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End Item -->

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
       <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Headline</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a href="http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/" target="_blank" class="label label-danger">Bootstrap 3 - Carousel Collection</a></p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End Item -->

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
       <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Headline</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End Item -->

  </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
```

The Java

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: false
});
var clickEvent = false;
$('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
        clickEvent = true;
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    if(!clickEvent) {
        var count = $('#myCarousel .nav').children().length -1;
        var current = $('#myCarousel .nav li.active');
        current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
        if(count == id) {
            $('#myCarousel .nav li').first().addClass('active');
        }
    }
    clickEvent = false;
});
});
```

and a little css

```
#myCarousel .nav a small {
    display:block;
}
#myCarousel .nav {
    background:#eee;
}
#myCarousel .nav a {
    border-radius:0px;
}

#myCarousel img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a crack at it and figured it out

[Here's a JSFIDDLE link](https://jsfiddle.net/27x8e997/4/)

Basically you add a background via the html and then because the carousel doesn't contain any images, you will need to set height etc in the css.

```
<div class="item" style="background: url(http://arti.us/clients/conversant/images/driving.jpg) no-repeat left center; background-size: cover;">
```